# Drupal change javascript navigation

Tags: javascript, drupal

I would like to know where and how I can change the JS line that refer to how fast the menu reveal

In this [orthopedics](https://www.kifidis-orthopedics.gr/) website for example. If you mouse over on the navigation it appears really fast. I want add a delay of 500 ms. I already tried but no luck.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help on creating examples for your questions.

Comment: Start by turning off, JS aggregation under Performance. After that I can possibly tell which script is executing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript code

find the line

```
 $('.dexp-dropdown ul li').hover(function() {
```

and move the code inside there in a setTimeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
// code that runs on hover
}, 500);
```

the aggregated file tha contains the code for the Dropdown menu is in 
https://www.kifidis-orthopedics.gr/sites/default/files/advagg_js/js__34rV67DsJTIYBUzVkI_gThD5BTcjM-NxunA7lLxqAQI__O_blo8HYG-y1HKzn0tuE4NZv31fj1jSbN307d8zF4Uk__iEu-eNTGZrBtMuFiHcqv2qN0hEpHgbA6Mo1YQ7rQOi4.js

cant be sure on which js file is in your project though

Comment: Thank you so much sir, unfortunately my boss dint want to wait and he bough it from a dev for 900 euros.... too bad but again thanks